# How can I keep all artifacts when building multi-stage Dockerfiles with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on a project that uses a multi-stage Dockerfile. This works fine for CircleCI, but I'm am not very experienced with Docker so I'm having trouble running things locally. From the documentation:

> The second FROM instruction starts a new build stage with the
> alpine:latest image as its base. The COPY --from=0 line copies just
> the built artifact from the previous stage into this new stage. The Go
> SDK and any intermediate artifacts are left behind, and not saved in
> the final image.

If I understand this correctly, it means that if I install a set of dependencies in stage 1, and another set in stage 2, then after I run `docker-compose up` I will only see some of dependencies installed. This is what is happening locally. However, in order to attach to a container and run the development server, I need *all* project dependencies to be installed. I have read here that it is possible to use the `--rm=false` parameter to the build command (I'm not sure if this refers to `docker build`, `docker-compose build`, or if there is any difference). I tried to add a `rm` setting to my docker-compose but apparently it doesn't exist.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
        container_name: my.container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            rm: false
        entrypoint: sh -c
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    app2:
        ...
```

My Dockerfile looks roughly like this:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.8-alpine3.12

FROM python:$PYTHON_VERSION AS base
ARG USER=myuser

# Install application run-time dependencies.
RUN addgroup -S ${USER} && \
    adduser -S -g ${USER} ${USER} && \
    apk add --no-cache \
            --upgrade \
        bash && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

FROM base AS builder

RUN mkdir /install
RUN mkdir /e2e_install
WORKDIR /install

# Install application build-time dependencies.
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache --upgrade \
    bash \
    build-base \
    libffi-dev \
    pcre-dev \
    linux-headers \
    zlib-dev \
    python3-dev \
    openssh \
    openssh-keygen \
    git \
    gcc \
    musl-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Install project and test dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --disable-pip-version-check pip==20.0.2

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
    --no-warn-script-location \
    --prefix=/install \
    --disable-pip-version-check -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY test_requirements.txt /tmp/test_requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
    --ignore-installed \
    --no-warn-script-location \
    --prefix=/install \
    --disable-pip-version-check -r /tmp/test_requirements.txt

# install e2e-test dependencies
COPY e2e/requirements.txt /tmp/e2e_test_requirements.txt
RUN cat /tmp/e2e_test_requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
                --ignore-installed \
                --disable-pip-version-check \
                --no-warn-script-location \
                --prefix=/e2e_install \
                -r /tmp/e2e_test_requirements.txt

# Tag version number into source code.
ARG VERSION_NUMBER=unversioned
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN sed -i -e "s/__version__ = \"unversioned\"/__version__ = \"${VERSION_NUMBER}\"/" external_api/__init__.py

# -------------------- e2e Image --------------------
FROM base as e2e-test
ARG USER=myuser

COPY --from=builder /e2e_install /usr/local

WORKDIR /opt/company/myapp
COPY --from=builder /source/e2e ./e2e
COPY --from=builder /source/scripts/entry_point.sh .

# Set file owner group,
RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /opt/company
ENTRYPOINT ["./entry_point.sh"]

# -------------------- Production Image --------------------
FROM base
ARG USER=myuser

# Copy necessary files from builder.
WORKDIR /opt/company
COPY --from=builder /install /usr/local
COPY --from=builder /source .

# Set file owner group,
RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /opt/company

# Run unit tests.
RUN PYTHONPATH=. pytest tests/unit_test --cov=. --cov-report=xml

COPY ./scripts/entry_point.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entry_point.sh"]
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, I get a bunch of these:

```
Step 20/26 : ARG VERSION_NUMBER=unversioned
 ---> Running in 1ce3e682b483
Removing intermediate container 1ce3e682b483
 ---> dcc4d4b6b4b5
Step 21/26 : WORKDIR /source
 ---> Running in c8d9c1349305
Removing intermediate container c8d9c1349305
```

When I attach to the container and try to run the Django development server, it doesn't work because the dependencies are not installed (even though the `docker-compose build` output shows that they were). I suppose this is because "intermediate containers" are being removed. I have tried to transform the multi-stage Dockerfile into a single-stage one, but I still keep getting "Removing intermediate container" messages and the dependencies are not all installed. Do I have to install all dependencies in a single RUN instruction? Is this the only way to have the dependencies all installed when I enter the container? Is there no way for me to keep this Dockerfile intact and somehow tell the docker-compose to stop "leaving intermediate artifacts behind" when building from it? Am I even using the word "artifact" correctly? I can't find a clear explanation and I'm not sure I fully understand what a "docker artifact" is.

Comment: Can you use an ordinary Python virtual environment for day-to-day development?

Comment: The project I'm working on uses a microservice architecture. There are 4 separate Python projects involved, they all have to communicate with each other, 2 of them have their own databases, other dependencies such as redis, rabbitmq. It is out of the question to install all these things locally.

Comment: You should be able to apply `--no-rm` to the `docker-compose build` command itself. You are correct that there appears no way to do this in the Compose file.

Comment: I think you have 2 choices. I'm unsure which is preferable and I've not tried either. First, determine which intermediate container includes the dependencies you need and that your Python script isn't moved by the `COPY ---from` commands. Edit the Compose file to reference the *intermediate* container image by ID. Second, merge the multi-stage Dockerfiles into one stage. As you wrote, the intent with multi-stage is often to clear up build|development dependencies that aren't needed at runtime and so this approach gives you everything back.

Comment: Second is probably the better option. It also gives you two types of images which I think is useful. The developer|development images that include everything and the runtime|end-user images that don't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to have separate docker-compose services, one for each of your images. You say there are 4 separate Python projects involved, so it sounds like there should be (at least) 4 services defined in your docker-compose.yaml.

So rather than defining all your services in one Dockerfile, I would expect each service to have its *own* Dockerfile, and to be defined separately in your `docker-compose.yaml`.

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  e2e:
    - build ./e2e
    ...
  production:
    - build ./production
    ...
```

You say all your services have to communicate with one another. Docker Compose makes this very easy as, for example, the `production` image can access the `e2e` image just using the URI `e2e`. (e.g. `curl e2e`).

Comment: Sorry, I shared a minimal version of my docker-compose with a single service, but I do in fact have many services, one for each Python app (+ postgres, redit, etc), and they do each have their own Dockerfile. The problem is that each of these Dockerfiles are multi-stage, and when I go into the container after the build, the dependencies are not there.